# Python: upload Pillow Image to Firebase storage bucket

Tags: python, firebase, python-imaging-library, firebase-storage

I'm trying to figure out how to upload a `Pillow` `Image` instance to a Firebase storage bucket. Is this possible?

Here's some code:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(file)
# how to upload to a firebase storage bucket?
```

I know there's a `gcloud-python` library but does this support `Image` instances? Is converting the image to a string my only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`gcloud-python`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) library is the correct library to use. It supports uploads from Strings, file pointers, and local files on the file system (see [the docs](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage-blobs.html)).

```
from PIL import Image
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id-here')
blob = bucket.blob('image.png')
# use pillow to open and transform the file
image = Image.open(file)
# perform transforms
image.save(outfile)
of = open(outfile, 'rb')
blob.upload_from_file(of)
# or... (no need to use pillow if you're not transforming)
blob.upload_from_filename(filename=outfile)
```

Comment: would `'bucket-id-here'` look like `'gs://example.appspot.com'` or just `'example.appspot.com'` ?

Comment: Just `example.appspot.com` :)

Comment: what does `outfile` represent here?

Comment: Why are you calling `image.save(outfile)` and then reading that file straight back in with `of = open(outfile, 'rb')`? Is there a way to skip this step and upload the `image` variable directly?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to directly upload the pillow image to firebase storage

```py
from PIL import Image
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app, storage

# Init firebase with your credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate("YOUR DOWNLOADED CREDENTIALS FILE (JSON)")
initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'YOUR FIREBASE STORAGE PATH (without gs://)'})

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob('image.jpg')

bs = io.BytesIO()
im = Image.open("test_image.jpg")
im.save(bs, "jpeg")

blob.upload_from_string(bs.getvalue(), content_type="image/jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I upload the PIL Image file directly to Firebase storage bucket. I used BytesIO object image_stream to hold the image data in memory instead of saving it to a temporary file and then uploading this stream directly to Firebase Storage using blob.upload_from_file. Finally, I closed the BytesIO object to free up memory.

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

cred = credentials.Certificate("path_to_your_service_account_key.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'your_storage_bucket_name.appspot.com'})

def upload_file_to_firebase(file, filename):
    bucket = storage.bucket()
    firebase_storage_path = f"images/{filename}"

    image = Image.fromarray(file.astype('uint8'))
    image_stream = BytesIO()
    image.save(image_stream, format='JPEG')
    image_stream.seek(0)
    
    blob = bucket.blob(firebase_storage_path)
    blob.upload_from_file(image_stream, content_type='image/jpg')

    blob.make_public()
    file_url = blob.public_url
    
    # print("File uploaded to Firebase Storage and URL:", file_url)

    image_stream.close()
    return file_url

for idx, image in enumerate(imgs):
    filename = f"{idx}.jpg"
    upload_file_to_firebase(image, filename)
```